# Mail Migration from Plesk 12 to MDaemon

Tags: email, migration, plesk

I want to transfer mail accounts and mail items of one the domains created in Plesk 12 (installed in 1st server) to Mdaemon (installed in 2nd server).

Is there any way for mail migration, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can export the accounts in Plesk into a CSV file, you can import them into MDaemon via the Accounts menu. The next step would be to migrate the email messages. You could do this a couple of ways. You could first archive all mail from Plesk using MailStore, then grant users access to their mail archives once they are connected to MDaemon, and restore their archived messages to their MDaemon inboxes, or you could use steps described in [this forum post.](http://lists.altn.com/WebX/.5985ff04)

Comment: is there any email address to technical support @ MDaemon? please let me know because I have another issue in our MDaemon email server. Thanks.